# Actualizar diferentes archivos de una tabla en LoopBack 4

Tags: loopback.io

A través del método `PATCH` (`/panel-opersis/update/{id}`) paso un `id`, el cual será actualizado con un JSON que irá en el cuerpo.

¿Hay una forma de enviar varios `id` con varios JSON para actualizar más de una fila en la tabla?

[image: Captura de pantalla]

Comment: La respuesta rápida es que NO. Mediante ese método solo puedes proporcionar un único `id` en la petición GET, por lo que no puedes actualizar más de un registro al mismo tiempo. Quizá haya otro punto final que permita actualizaciones múltiples, como un `POST` o `PATCH` a `/panel-opensis` directamente u otro similar.

Comment: Se podría modificar el Path para recibir un arreglo de id?

Comment: Eso depende de tu punto final, de cómo lo tengas configurado y qué permitas. El método `PATCH` con JSON está definido aquí [https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902), donde envías una matriz de valores con cada operación que deseas realizar, pero necesitas que tu punto final (tu endpoint) lo soporte, y en ese caso no sé decirte si lookback.io lo soporta.